# VueJS: Is it possible to use spread operator for computed properties?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuejs3

I just wonder if I could do the code below less ugly.

In the component I have a property `person`. I'd like to use fields of the `person` object in my template without prepending each field with `person.something`. But the only way I know is below.

**This is what I have atm:**

(*Please consider the code below as just an example, it's not a real one*)

```
{
  name: 'Demo',
  props: {
    person: {
      type: Object,
      default: {}
    }
  },
  computed: {
    firstName() {
      return this.person.firstName
    },
    lastName() {
      return this.person.lastName
    },
    age() {
      return this.person.age
    },
    gender() {
      return this.person.gender
    }
  }
}
```

**This is what I want to have instead** (kind of):

```
{
  name: 'Demo',
  props: {
    person: {
      type: Object,
      default: {}
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...this.person // <-- something like this would be better if only it would work
  }
}
```

**Some assumptions**

I assume that things like this should be possible, because we have `mapGetters` of vuex:

```
 computed: {
    ...mapGetters({ something: SOMETHING })
  },
```

Comment: It will not work - computed properties must be either a function or a pair of getter/setter. The spread operator can work `inside` a computed property - but in your case it will be simpler to just use the `person` object as a whole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With vue 3 or the composition api plugin for vue 2 you could use `toRefs` to spread the prop value inside the `setup` hook :

```
import {toRefs} from 'vue'//vue3
//import {toRefs} from '@vue/composition-api'//vue 2

export default{
  name: 'Demo',
  props: {
    person: {
      type: Object,
      default: {}
    }
  },
setup(props){

return {...toRefs(props.person)}
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I see your point but what you want is not possible.

The main problem is `this`. We work with Options API. What is `computed`? An object that is passed into a Vue and Vue creates new instance with computed property for each function (or get/set pair) inside `computed` object. That means the spread operator is executed **at the time component instance does not exist yet** which means there is no `this`

`mapGetters` works because it's input are just static strings. If you had some static description of the `Person` object - for example some schema generated from Open API specification - you could create `mapProperties` helper and use it to generate computed props...

**Edit:**
Yes, there is a way to create computed props dynamically in `beforeCreate` by modifying [$options object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options) - at least it was possible in Vue 2. Not sure about Vue 3. In both cases it is documented to be read only and Vue 3 is somehow more strict in forcing "read onlyness". However this is very different approach from the one in your question...

The approach is demonstrated for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58412308/381282)

Comment: I see... this is pity. But just curious, in theory it's possible to create computed properties dynamically (inside `beforeCreated` maybe). So in theory I think it's possible to create a function like `mapGetters` which wrap object's fields and add them... But it's a mess for sure

Comment: @spabn Yes that approach is possible (updated my answer) but it has it's downsides. For example component using this approach requires the `person` prop value must be "complete" at the moment component is created - not `null` (usually with async) , no adding properties later etc. And the code is less readable too. I don't think it's worth it...